# Building fftw for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, compilation, fftw

I'm trying to build fftw for iOS. 
I found this question:
[How to link third party libraries like fftw3 and sndfile to an iPhone project in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588904/how-to-link-third-party-libraries-like-fftw3-and-sndfile-to-an-iphone-project-in)

And tried running the shell script, but I am getting the errors shown below.

```
make[2]: *** [bench] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
lipo: unknown architecture specification flag: armv7s in specifying input file -arch armv7s ios-library/libfftw3f_armv7s.a
lipo: known architecture flags are: any little big ppc64 x86_64 ppc970-64 ppc i386 m68k hppa sparc m88k i860 veo arm ppc601 ppc603 ppc603e ppc603ev ppc604 ppc604e ppc750 ppc7400 ppc7450 ppc970 i486 i486SX pentium i586 pentpro i686 pentIIm3 pentIIm5 pentium4 m68030 m68040 hppa7100LC veo1 veo2 veo3 veo4 armv4t armv5 xscale armv6 armv7 armv7f armv7k
lipo: Usage: lipo [input_file] ... [-arch <arch_type> input_file] ... [-info] [-detailed_info] [-output output_file] [-create] [-arch_blank <arch_type>] [-thin <arch_type>] [-remove <arch_type>] ... [-extract <arch_type>] ... [-extract_family <arch_type>] ... [-verify_arch <arch_type> ...] [-replace <arch_type> <file_name>] ...
```

I am a total nooby when it comes to compiling for iOS so any help is much appreciated. 
It looks like it can't find the armv7s architecture specified...

If I leave in only the first part, for the armv7 architecture, I get the following errors:

```
Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch armv7 -std=gnu99 -mfpu=neon
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/davidmenard/Desktop/fftw-3.3.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
cp: .libs/libfftw3f.a: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My XCode compilers were not getting along, because I had both XCode 4 and XCode5-DP5 installed. Using the latest compiler fixed my errors.

Answer (score 1):

I  needed to recompile my framework: double check those armv7s to not miss at that 2 place:

[image]

For me the problem was solved, hopefully it will help a few of you!