# How to link fftw3 in Xcode? (Mac)

Tags: xcode, fftw

i followed script on ( [How do I link third party libraries like fftw3 and sndfile to an iPhone project in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588904/how-to-link-third-party-libraries-like-fftw3-and-sndfile-to-an-iphone-project-in) )
 but i got an Error. firstly by configuration :

> ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin
>   --enable-float --enable-neon .... checking whether C compiler accepts -march=armv7 -mfpu=neon... no configure: error: Need a compiler with support for -march=armv7 -mfpu=neon

and at the end by copying the ARM library to a temporary location :

> lipo -arch armv7 $RESULT_DIR/libfftw3f_armv7.a -arch armv7s
>   $RESULT_DIR/libfftw3f_armv7s.a -arch i386 $RESULT_DIR/libfftw3f_i386.a
>   -arch x86_64 $RESULT_DIR/libfftw3f_x86_64.a -arch arm64 $RESULT_DIR/libfftw3f_arm64.a -create -output $RESULT_DIR/libfftw3f.a
>
> lipo: unknown architecture specification flag: arm64 in specifying
>   input file -arch arm64 ios-library/libfftw3f_arm64.a
>
> lipo: known
>   architecture flags are: any little big ppc64 x86_64 ppc970-64 ppc i386
>   m68k hppa sparc m88k i860 veo arm ppc601 ppc603 ppc603e ppc603ev
>   ppc604 ppc604e ppc750 ppc7400 ppc7450 ppc970 i486 i486SX pentium i586
>   pentpro i686 pentIIm3 pentIIm5 pentium4 m68030 m68040 hppa7100LC veo1
>   veo2 veo3 veo4 armv4t armv5 xscale armv6 armv6m armv7 armv7f armv7s
>   armv7k armv7m armv7em
>
> lipo: Usage: lipo [input_file] ... [-arch
>   input_file] ... [-info] [-detailed_info] [-output output_file]
>   [-create] [-arch_blank ] [-thin ] [-remove ] ... [-extract ] ...
>   [-extract_family ] ... [-verify_arch ...] [-replace ] ...

i am using the gcc49 and Mac OS X 10.9.2, iOS 7.1. any idea ? thanks

Comment: But that error message clearly specifies your problem, doesn't it? `lipo` does not know any architecture named `arm64`.

Comment: im am a beginner. thanks, so when i will take the library "/libfftw3f_arm64.a" away it will work?

Comment: and whats about the first error?
that i need a compiler ...

Comment: when i am taking some library from lipo away, its showing me this error :
lipo: specifed architecture type (armv7) for file (ios-library/libfftw3f_armv7.a) does not match its cputype (16777223) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (9))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by First Error, the configure should be like this:

./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin --enable-float

( without --enable-neon )
 and the second Error, its because the libraries are all from the arch  x86_64. they should have the right architecture ( libfftw3f_i386.a should have the arch. i386.a and libfftw3f_armv7s.a the arch. armv7s.a and so on )

i could make the right library for FFTW by using macports (or u can use homebrew) to install a universal build of the library for use with OpenFrameworks.

type this into a terminal window:

> sudo port install fftw-3 +universal

the port install command will place the fftw3.h header file in your_HD/opt/local/include folder, and the libfftw3.a library in your_HD/opt/local/lib folder. To use the library in your OF project, add these two files to your project via the menu option Project -> Add to project...

thanks for every help and special thanks @Adam Freeman