# how to build fftw library for iOS

Tags: ios, cross-compiling, fftw

I need to build fftw for iOS. And I follow the solution here: 
[How do I link third party libraries like fftw3 and sndfile to an iPhone project in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588904/how-to-link-third-party-libraries-like-fftw3-and-sndfile-to-an-iphone-project-in/25834570#25834570)

Now I have the library. And I use the lipo -info to check and find that it support all the arm and i386. But when i try to use it in my iPhone app. I got the errors like : 
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_fftw_malloc", referenced from:

I use XCode6-beta6 with OSX10.10

Answer (score 1):

solved. I build the library using configure float precision. And I call the function with double precision. And of course it can't been linked. The nm help me to check the symbol in the static library..

Comment: Hi, could you please share how to do this? I need this for my project also.
Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Hey @AndrewSmith  I just followed the instruction by the link.